# Reconstruct fractal in Apollonian Gasket style

Tags: fractals

I wondered if the following picture can be reconstructed programmatically:

[image: http://cdn.superbwallpapers.com/wallpapers/artistic/fractal-apolonnian-circles-26322-1366x768.jpg]

It seems it has some features of an Apollonian Gasket (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket) but also includes other pattern which I don't recognise.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This picture is made with open source software [Apophysis](http://www.apophysis.org/). It is a so called fractal flame - fractal structure made with ifs (iteration functions system).